# How to run a query to deactivate quotes as Magento code?

Tags: database, magento-community, quote, query

I need a Magento code query to set all quotes to Not active. 
How do I write this query as a Magento code?

```
UPDATE `sales_flat_quote` SET `is_active`=0 WHERE `customer_email`='user@gmail.com'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual Magento way would be to load the collection first, then save the attribute for each item. However, this means there are at least n+1 queries for n quotes (1x SELECT and nx UPDATE)

For your case, that should be okay, since there won't be huge numbers of quotes for one email address but if you really need to optimize this into one single update query, you can use this code to create the query manually:

```
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$resource = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/quote');
$connection->update(
    $resource->getMainTable(),
    array('is_active' => 0),
    array('customer_email = ?' => 'user@gmail.com' ));
```

Comment: Thank you fschmengler for the solution and the explanation. Works like magic!

Answer (score 2):

**First,get Quote collection By using below code:**

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/quote_collection');
```

**then filter this collection by Customer email address and active.**

```
$collection
->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
->addAttributeToFilter('customer_email', 'user@gmail.com');
```

**Then update all quotes**

```
foreach($collection as $quote) {
    $quote->setIsActive(false);
    $quote->_getResource()->saveAttribute($quote, 'is_active');
}
```

Comment: elad ,please check... i have modify the code

Comment: Thank you 7ochem for noticing the mistake. Thank you Amir for the code. Now the code is doing what it suppose to do!

Comment: That will be really slow for big batches